# How would you go about solving this? Old-Fashion Student/Course/School Code. Here's my approach:

Tags: c++, class, structure, implementation

I'm just curious if my way of thinking is incorrect. Would my way of thinking work, or would I need pointers/references in my code? How would you approach this? I'm just rough-sketching at this point. Look at my comments for my concerns. Mainly curious as to if I should use pointers, and how to reference classes in my Student class.

Shortened Example Problem: Make a program that lets you:
1.) Create/Delete a Student from School
2.) Create/Delete a Course from school
3.) Add/Remove a student from a Course
4.) Print a list of students in a course
5.) Print a list of courses a student is in.

```
class Student
{
    public:
    string name;
    int id;
    Student(){};//Default Construct
    Student(int idin,string namein)
    {
        id=idin;
        name=namein;
    }
    void PrintClasses()
    {
        //Umm... I can't create a Class Vector yet because Class is declared under this.. Hmm... Not sure on this part.
    }
};


class Class
{
public:
    int id;
    string name;
    Student students_in_class; //Is this the right way to store students in the class?

    Class(){};//Default Constructor
    Class(int idin, string namein)
        {
        id=idin;
        name=namein;
        }
    void PrintStudents()
    {
        for (i=0;i<students_in_class.size();i++)
        {
            cout<<students_in_class.id<<'\n';
        }
    }
};

class School
{
public:
    Vector<Student> studentlist;
    Vector<Class> classlist;

    //This is where you do everything.
    void StudentAdd(int id,string name)
    {
        //Adds a student to the school
        Student mystudent=Student(id,name);
        studentlist.push_back(mystudent);
    }
    void StudentAdd2Course(int student_id,int course_id)
    {
        for (i=0;i<classlist.size();i++)
            {
                if(classlist[i].id==course_id)
                {
                    //Correct Class ID Found. Now find student Id
                    for (int j=0;j<studentlist.size();j++)
                        if(studentlist[j].id==student_id)
                            classlist[i].students_in_class.push_back(studentlist[j]);//Push Student in class list
                }
            }

    }
    void StudentRemoveFromCourse(int student_id,int course_id)
    {
        for (i=0;i<classlist.size();i++)
            {
                if(classlist[i].id==course_id)
                {
                    //Correct Class ID Found. Now find student Id
                    for (int j=0;j<studentlist.size();j++)
                        if(studentlist[j].id==student_id)
                            classlist[i].students_in_class.erase(studentlist[j]);//Push Student in class list
                }
            }

    }

    //Other functions like create class, delete class, etc

};
```

Comment: Shouldn't the property `students_in_class` under the class `Class` be a `Vector<Student>` ?

Comment: This sounds more like a database than a C++ problem...

Comment: @Kerrek -- sound more like an interview question ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when designing something object-oriented I try to start with simple classes, and let other classes act upon them like puppets (no phun intended, despite modeling students).

In this case, it is a straight-forward job with Student being a simple class, course contain Students, and Scool contains Courses (and maybe students).

The only complication is printing the courses a student takes. I would say that, conceptually, it should not be in the Student class, as it needs more information than a simple object can provide.

When it comes to implementing it, you could either loop through the existing data, or you could maintain extra information. If you do the latter, make sure that the extra information is consistent in the normal system.

Ps. Look up how you write loops using iterators in C++.

Comment: thanks. I have tried an attempt at this, but am failing. The size of my Vector of 'Students' does not update when I push a student back. I posted a followup question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014050/whats-wrong-with-my-logic-my-vector-or-an-object-doesnt-push-back-a-new-objec