# What's wrong with my logic? My Vector or an object doesn't push_back a new object. Stays at size of 0

Tags: c++, database, class, object, vector

I worked on this all day and am stuck on my logic in how I approached this problem. Whenever I have a `Vector<class> blah`. And I try to `blah.push_back(class())`, it doesn't, update or work.

I've been researching and I think it has to do with pointers and references. I tried changing `Vector<Student> blah` to `Vector<Student*> blah`, and using 'new' `Student()` when I'm pushing it back, but it still yields the same result. I think I'm defining the vectors wrong.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
using namespace std;

class Student
{
  public:
    string first_name;
    string last_name;
    string major;
    int student_id;

    Student() {};

    Student(int no, string name1, string name2, string majorin)
    {
      first_name = name1;
      last_name = name2;
      student_id = no;
      major = majorin;
    }

};

class Course
{
  public:
    Vector<Student> Students;
    int max_enrollment;
    int course_id;
    string course_title;

    Course() {};

    Course(int no_in,int max_in,string title_in)
    {
      max_enrollment=max_in;
      course_title=title_in;
      course_id=no_in;
    }

};

unsigned int split(const std::string &txt, vector<std::string> &strs, char ch)
{
  unsigned int pos = txt.find( ch );
  unsigned int initialPos = 0;
  strs.clear();

  // Decompose statement
  while( pos != std::string::npos ) {
    strs.push_back( txt.substr( initialPos, pos - initialPos + 1 ) );
    initialPos = pos + 1;

    pos = txt.find( ch, initialPos );
  }

  // Add the last one
  strs.push_back( txt.substr( initialPos, std::min( pos, txt.size() ) - initialPos + 1 ) );

  return strs.size();
}

class University
{
  public:
    Vector<Student> studentlist;
    Vector<Course> courselist;

    University() {};

  void Parse(string input)
  {
    //Case Statements
    vector<string> temp;
    split( input, temp, ' ' );
    cout<<temp[0];
    if (temp[0]=="S ")
    {
      //Add Student to University
      //Student* myStudent=new );
      cout<<studentlist.size()<<endl;
      //Student(atoi(temp[1].c_str()),temp[2],temp[3],temp[4])
      studentlist.push_back(Student()); 
    }
    else if (temp[0]=="C")
    {
      //Add Course to University
      Course myCourse=Course(atoi(temp[1].c_str()),atoi(temp[2].c_str()),temp[3]);
      courselist.push_back(myCourse);
    }
    else if (temp[0]=="L")
    {
      //Add Student to Course list
      //Not Implemented-Find Course by temp[1] which is a int
      for (int i=0;i<courselist.size();i++)
      {
        if (courselist.at(i).course_id==atoi(temp[1].c_str()))
        {
          courselist.at(i).max_enrollment=atoi(temp[1].c_str());
        }
      }
    }
    else if (temp[0]=="A")
    {
      for (int i=0;i<courselist.size();i++)
      {
        if (courselist.at(i).course_id==atoi(temp[1].c_str()))
        {
          for (int j=0;j<studentlist.size();j++)
          {
            if (studentlist.at(j).student_id==atoi(temp[1].c_str()))
        {
          Student mystudent=studentlist.at(j);
          courselist.at(i).Students.push_back(mystudent);
        }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else if (temp[0]=="D")
    {
      for (int i=0;i<courselist.size();i++)
      {
        if (courselist.at(i).course_id==atoi(temp[1].c_str()))
        {
          for (int j=0;j<courselist.at(i).Students.size();j++)
          {
            if (courselist.at(i).Students.at(j).student_id==atoi(temp[1].c_str()))
            {
              //Student mystudent=courselist.at(i).Students.at(j);
          courselist.at(i).Students.erase(courselist.at(i).Students.begin()+j);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else if (temp[0]=="PS")
    {
      cout<<"--Student Report--\n";
    }
    else if (temp[0]=="PC")
    {
      cout<<"--Student Report--\n";
      for (int i=0;i<courselist.size();i++)
      {
        for (int j=0;j<courselist.at(i).Students.size();j++)
        {
          string first_name=courselist.at(i).Students.at(j).first_name;
          string last_name=courselist.at(i).Students.at(j).last_name;
          string major=courselist.at(i).Students.at(j).major;
          //Waiting List var
          cout<<first_name<<" "<<last_name<<" "<<major<<"\n";
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  string input;
  while(1==1)
  {
    cout<<"Command:: ";
    getline(cin,input);
    //cout<<input;

    University myUniversity;
    myUniversity.Parse(input); //Input is in the format X Name Name etc etc. Arguments separated by spaces
    cout<<"DEBUG:"<<myUniversity.studentlist.size();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know what `std::vector` is, but what is `Vector`?

Comment: @FredLarson: Bjarne uses it in his book "Programming: Principles and Practice using C++".  It's basically a vector with bounds checking. http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h

Comment: man, you're code is extremely unreadable

Comment: yeah, sorry :/ which parts are most un-readable? I'm trying this year to clean up my style

Comment: Any suggestions on where to look/redesign?

Comment: Instead of doing `while (1==1)` why not `while (true)`? Although the compiler will make that for you, I think the later is more clear about the intentions.

Comment: Please don't edit your question out into oblivion! This is a Q&A site and people might want to see your question in the future. But the only thing they'll see is that your problem got "FIXED"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Error! Can't believe you spent so long on this! Haha.

You defined your University inside your while loop!

I'm not familiar with C++ (learning myself), but I think it should also be done using pointers and references and the keyword 'new'.

Can someone explain the difference between the way he's doing it and other ways I've seen where people use Student mystudent=new Student(); etc etc

Comment: Wow... it's working now! Thanks a lot.

You also think I'm doing this the wrong way?

Comment: @CREW: No! You shouldn't be doing anything with pointers and the keyword `new`. C++ is not Java. Keep doing what you're doing, you're on the right track. The difference between the way you do it and `Student* mystudent=new Student();` is that `Student* mystudent=new Student();` is just a stupid way of asking for trouble with practically zero gain.